# Running `scp` script from exec function in PHP

Tags: php, bash, apache

I am trying to SCP a file from one server to an external mail server.

In my code I use:

```
exec('/full/path/to/script.sh' '/full/path/to/file_to_transfer.txt');
```

In my Script.sh I have:

```
scp  -i /full/path/to/private.key $1 [user]@[ip]:/opt/mailman/mailman-bundler/venv-3.4/lib/python3.4/site-packages/mailman/templates/en/.
```

When I call the script with a file via the CLI, the script runs fine and the file transfers. When I run it in PHP as the apache/www-data user the `exec()` call fails with a code 126, which translates to: "Command invoked cannot execute".

Extra notes:

I noticed for the first time every user tries this, they get a confirmation of the RSA fingerprint. I thought that the script was stalling on that and that would be the problem. I manually went in as the www-data user and confirmed the fingerprint. The problem still exists.

After many tries, I created a replica set up of the folders, scripts and files and opened the permissions up completely - all the way down to root to see if I had the wrong permissions set. I still receive a 126 error.

My project manager was against using the idea of using the [PHP SSH2/SCP functions](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ssh2-scp-send.php) for the reason that if the fundamental bash script is failing, then it will fail for the same reasons with the SSH2/SCP functions as well.

I have a hunch that the above is the wrong idea because the script works via CLI and not via Apache, while the PHP SCP functions are meant to be run from Apache.

Any insight on where my problem (calling SCP inside a script from an `exec()` call) stems from or hard evidence that the PHP SCP functions will work would be appreciated.

Comment: The use of exec may be disabled as configured in the php.ini. Is this something you have control over? If not, perhaps you could look into using the ssh2 class http://php.net/manual/en/intro.ssh2.php

Comment: exec isn't disabled. I will look into the ssh2 class though, thank you for the reference.

Comment: This is the kind of thing where the environment could make a huge difference. For example, if your server is running selinux. Are you able to increase the verbosity of your logs?

Answer (score 0):

I recently published a project that allows PHP to obtain and interact with a real Bash shell. Get it here: https://github.com/merlinthemagic/MTS

After downloading you would simply use the following code:

```
//if the script does not require root permissions you can change the
//second argument on getShell() to false. That will return a bash shell
//with permissions from www-data or apache user.

$shell    = \MTS\Factories::getDevices()->getLocalHost()->getShell('bash', true);
$return1  = $shell->exeCmd('/full/path/to/script.sh' '/full/path/to/file_to_transfer.txt');
```